# separate click events for each column in list view

Tags: android

How can I have separate click events for each column in `listview`? I have two `textviews` in each row of the `listview`. I want to handle two separate events for each `textview`.

How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: I think you may think of TableLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can handle that click event by defining the onClickListener for TextView in you custom adapter where you set the TextView values

here is the snippet code for this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        converView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v){
                    // do whatever you want
              };
        });
        viewHolder.textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        textView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v){
                    // do whatever you want
              };
        });
     }
..........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your custom Listview using an adapter..

In your getview() set up the click listeners for your Textview..

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) 
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    TextView textViewTwo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_two);
    if (textViewTwo != null)
        textViewTwo.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("Sample", "Clicked on tag: " + v.getTag());
    // Do something here, like start new activity.
}
```