# Display information in table form and be able to click items independently in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to write a small Android app with [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) to allow the user to order items that are sold by 2 different sellers. The user will see a table on the screen listing the price (and quantity) available to buy at a given seller. The products are listed in rows and the product name would be in the middle column. The client will decide where to buy a given product and clicking on the corresponding cell the product goes into the basket (each click will increment the quantity in the basket by 1). It is also possible that the user might want to buy product A from more than one seller (for example because one hasn't enough quantity on sale).

*What is the best way to achieve this without buying third-party libraries?* 
With a custom listView I can display all this information and if I work with one listView only every seller will scroll in sync by default given they are all on the same list. 
But the problem with this is that I cannot identify which column I selected (so which seller the client has chosen for a given product).

**The table would look like this:**

### Seller_1 - Product - Seller_2

p1(A) -     A  -   p2(A)

---

p1(B) -     B  -   p2(B)

---

**EDIT**
As suggested below, I am using one listview and handling the click events within the custom adapter. The below adapter assumes there are two sellers with prices displayed in the textviews *txtBuy_One* and *txtBuy_One*. 
Each product is an object of type *dbQuotes* and each click need to increase the quantity of the corresponding seller by 1 and update the information in the DB (table *dbQuotes*). The quantity is also displayed in the textview *txtQ_One* and *txtQ_Two*. 
If I decide to reuse the views (as I should), the problem are 2:

1. when I click, the first time the quantities increase by 1, as expected. But then any subsequent click increases by 2, 3, 4, 5... depending on the cumulative number of clicks over the whole listview.
2. the textviews that should show the quantities get messed up if I scroll the list. For example, product that had 0 quantity, after the scroll have different values.

I avoided the issues above by forcing the code to inflate the row every time but I know there must be a better solution to this, although my listview is not huge and there should be no significant impact on performance. 
I also added a method in the custom adapter to notify the adapter that the dataset has changed. 
This way the code works as expected but I am wondering if there is a better way. Two concerns I have:

- I am forcing the code to inflate the view every time and if the list gets bigger it might affect performance
- the method *updateAdapter()* makes a query to the DB everytime there is a click event (which means some quantity has been changed and the corresponding product has updated fields in the DB) and this might contribute to lowering performance.

  ```
  class MyListViewAdapterQuotes : BaseAdapter<dbQuotes>
  {
       public List<dbQuotes> mItems;
       private Context mContext;
       private int mRowLayout;
       private string[] mAlternatingColors;
       private string mdbPath;
       private TextView txtBuy_One;
       private TextView txtBuy_Two;
       private TextView txtQ_One;
       private TextView txtQ_Two;

  // Default constructor
  public MyListViewAdapterQuotes(Context context, List<dbQuotes> items, int rowLayout, string dbPath)
  {
      mItems = items;
      mContext = context;
      mRowLayout = rowLayout;
      mdbPath = dbPath;
  }

  public void updateAdapter()
  {
      mItems.Clear();
      mItems.AddRange(helpers.getQuotes(mdbPath));
      this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  // Tells how many rows are in the dataset
  public override int Count
  {
      get { return mItems.Count; }
  }

  // Return a row identifier
  public override long GetItemId(int position)
  {
      return position;
  }

  // Return the data associated with a particular row
  public override dbQuotes this[int position]
  {
      get { return mItems[position]; }
  }

  // Return a view for each row
  public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
      View row = convertView;
      // force to inflate view every time
      //if (row == null)
      {
          row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_rowQuotes, null, false);
      }

      var db = new SQLiteConnection(mdbPath);

      // updateRow gets the row view and the object to update
      updateRow(row, mItems[position]);

      txtBuy_One.Click += delegate {
          mItems[position].Q_One = mItems[position].Q_One + 1;
          db.Update(mItems[position]);
          var quote = db.Query<dbQuotes>("select * from Quotes where ID = ?", mItems[position].ID).FirstOrDefault();
          updateRow(row, quote);
      };

      txtBuy_Two.Click += delegate {
          mItems[position].Q_Two = mItems[position].Q_Two + 1;
          db.Update(mItems[position]);
          var quote = db.Query<dbQuotes>("select * from Quotes where ID = ?", mItems[position].ID).FirstOrDefault();
          updateRow(row, quote);
      };

      return row;
  }

  private View updateRow(View row, dbQuotes quote)
  {
      txtBuy_One = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Buy_One);
      txtBuy_One.Text = quote.One.ToString("0.#");

      txtBuy_Two = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Buy_Two);
      txtBuy_Two.Text = quote.Two.ToString("0.#");

      txtQ_One = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.q_One);
      txtQ_One.Text = quote.Q_One.ToString();

      txtQ_Two = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.q_Two);
      txtQ_Two.Text = quote.Q_Two.ToString();

      return row;
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Why can't you identify which column is clicked? You could use different `textviews` in your cell for your sellers and then you add an `textView.setOnClickListener` for each `textview`

Comment: Do you mean I should add the click event inside the custom adapter? Cause at the moment I have the myList.ItemClick event outside the adapter (from the code of the activity that hosts the list) and that is only giving me the position of the item I clicked that I access with e.position

Comment: Yes. See this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942068/separate-click-events-for-each-column-in-list-view

Comment: I added the click event and I am able to see that clicks trigger separate events. But, after adding a small textview close to each seller to show hom much quantity has been bought (i.e. how many times the price textview of the seller has been clicked), I noticed that after I scroll the list the quantities get messed up and are not consistent with original user clicks. How can I avoid this?

Comment: There must be a bug in your adapter. Update your question and insert the full code

Comment: Hi, the custom adapter has been added to the question. Hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve. In summary, I want to click on cells showing the price that each seller applies to a given product. Once I click I want to update the quantity information in the DB and also display the number is a small textview close to the textview where the prices are displayed. Problem is that clicks are not always increasing the quantity by 1 (sometimes it is by 2, 3...) and that after scroll all the displayed infor gets messed up. Only the static info (i.e. prices and product names don't get affected).

Comment: I have updated the code and it seems to work now but the solutions I adopted are not efficient. So I still hope to get some help to find a better way to achieve the same goal.